# Can't launch Finder window from terminal on Mojave

Tags: macos, bash, mac, open

`open` isn't behaving as expected on Mojave. Running

```
open /Library/
```

gives

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Library.
```

This happens regardless of the opening location. I'm totally lost here. Any hints?

Edit:

It is working now after letting my laptop go to sleep for a while, for whatever reason. If you run into this issue, I guess just try a reboot.

Comment: Try "sudo open" instead. The Library you're trying to open isn't the one in your home directory, but System's. If you want to open your own, add a tilde before the first slash.

Comment: @Didier that was just an example; even `open .` in home was giving the same output. It's working now after letting the device sleep, for whatever reason.